AWS Lambda docker container write file
Creating a docker container that can be used with Lambda, which will download the image from S3 in temp folder, create marker files (3 files will be created) and upload the generated files to S3.
I have the following content for Dockerfile
# Use AWS Lambda's base image for Node.js with Alpine Linux
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:20

# Set the working directory in the container
#WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Install production dependencies
RUN npm install

# Install aws-sdk
RUN npm install aws-sdk

# Copy the rest of the application code to the container
COPY . ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
#COPY lambda.js ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Command to run the app when invoked in AWS Lambda
CMD ["lambda.handler"]

and lambda.js file as
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

// Configure S3 client
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

async function downloadImageFromS3(bucket, key, downloadPath) {
    const params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: key };
    console.log('getting s3 object with params: ', params);
    const data = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
    console.log('writing file to download path: ', downloadPath);
    fs.writeFileSync(downloadPath, data.Body);
}

async function uploadMarkerToS3(bucket, key, filePath) {
    console.log('reading file content from key: ', key);
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key,
        Body: fileContent
    };
    console.log('saving s3 object with params: ', params);
    await s3.putObject(params).promise();
}

async function generateMarker() {
    const imagePath = '/app/images/sample.png';  // Image path inside container
    const outputDir = '/app/output';  // Output directory inside container

    // Run marker generation
    const command = `node app.js -i ${imagePath}`;
    console.log('generating marker with command: ', command);
    execSync(command, { encoding: 'utf-8' });
}

exports.handler = async function(event) {
    console.log('event is: ', event);

    // Get environment variables passed from Lambda
    const bucket = event.S3_BUCKET;
    const key = event.S3_KEY;
    const outputPrefix = event.OUTPUT_PREFIX || 'markers';

    console.log('config: bucket - ', bucket);
    console.log('config: key - ', key);
    console.log('config: outputPrefix - ', outputPrefix);

    console.log('list: ', execSync(`ls -la`, {encoding: 'utf-8'}));
    console.log('env...: ', process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT);

    const localImagePath = `${process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/images/sample.png`;
    const localOutputDir = `${process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/output`;

    // 1. Download the image from S3
    console.log('downloading from s3 to local path')
    await downloadImageFromS3(bucket, key, localImagePath);
    console.log('s3 download complete')

    // 2. Run marker generation
    console.log('generating marker')
    await generateMarker();
    console.log('marker generation completed')

    // 3. Upload generated marker files to S3
    console.log('reading files from output directory: ', localOutputDir);
    const outputFiles = fs.readdirSync(localOutputDir);
    console.log('output files are: ', outputFiles);
    for (const file of outputFiles) {
        console.log('file object: ', file);
        const outputFilePath = path.join(localOutputDir, file);
        console.log('file path: ', outputFilePath);
        const s3Key = `${outputPrefix}/${file}`;
        console.log('s3 file key: ', s3Key);
        console.log('uploading file to s3')
        await uploadMarkerToS3(bucket, s3Key, outputFilePath);
        console.log('file uploaded to s3');
    }

    console.log('Marker generation and upload completed successfully.');
};

The function is executed till downloadImageFromS3 then it fails at fs.writeFileSync(downloadPath, data.Body); with the following logs output
START RequestId: 98428165-89de-4e11-b2bf-32c27d6e6c67 Version: $LATEST
2024-10-22T05:16:39.251Z    98428165-89de-4e11-b2bf-32c27d6e6c67    INFO    event is:  {
  S3_BUCKET: 'tapxreality-media',
  S3_KEY: 'media/uploads/422909c0-b46d-45e2-9692-8020b8324a58/2024/10/20241002_258276_46PM.png',
  OUTPUT_PREFIX: 'value3'
}
2024-10-22T05:16:39.305Z    98428165-89de-4e11-b2bf-32c27d6e6c67    INFO    config: bucket -  tapxreality-media
2024-10-22T05:16:39.305Z    98428165-89de-4e11-b2bf-32c27d6e6c67    INFO    config: key -  media/uploads/422909c0-b46d-45e2-9692-8020b8324a58/2024/10/20241002_258276_46PM.png
2024-10-22T05:16:39.305Z    98428165-89de-4e11-b2bf-32c27d6e6c67    INFO    config: outputPrefix -  value3
2024-10-22T05:16:39.468Z    98428165-89de-4e11-b2bf-32c27d6e6c67    INFO    list:  total 73
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root  1024 Oct 22 05:15 .
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root  4096 Oct 22 04:41 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   458 Oct 21 13:27 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  3023 Oct 21 13:18 README.md
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 19253 Oct 20 18:47 app.js
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root    60 Oct 20 12:10 demo
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    60 Oct 20 12:25 input
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   530 Oct 22 02:46 lambda.Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  3462 Oct 22 05:15 lambda.js
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  1024 Oct 20 12:10 libs
drwxr-xr-x 107 root root  3072 Oct 22 02:47 node_modules
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  1024 Oct 20 12:44 output
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 33822 Oct 20 12:18 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   426 Oct 21 17:55 package.json
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    60 Oct 20 12:38 sample
2024-10-22T05:16:39.468Z    98428165-89de-4e11-b2bf-32c27d6e6c67    INFO    env...:  /var/task
2024-10-22T05:16:39.468Z    98428165-89de-4e11-b2bf-32c27d6e6c67    INFO    downloading from s3 to local path
2024-10-22T05:16:39.468Z    98428165-89de-4e11-b2bf-32c27d6e6c67    INFO    getting s3 object with params:  {
  Bucket: 'tapxreality-media',
  Key: 'media/uploads/422909c0-b46d-45e2-9692-8020b8324a58/2024/10/20241002_258276_46PM.png'
}
2024-10-22T05:16:40.929Z    98428165-89de-4e11-b2bf-32c27d6e6c67    INFO    writing file to download path:  /var/task/images/sample.png
2024-10-22T05:16:41.109Z    98428165-89de-4e11-b2bf-32c27d6e6c67    ERROR   Invoke Error    {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/images/sample.png'","code":"ENOENT","errno":-2,"syscall":"open","path":"/var/task/images/sample.png","stack":["Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/images/sample.png'","    at Object.openSync (node:fs:573:18)","    at Object.writeFileSync (node:fs:2380:35)","    at downloadImageFromS3 (/var/task/lambda.js:14:8)","    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)","    at async exports.handler (/var/task/lambda.js:65:9)"]}
END RequestId: 98428165-89de-4e11-b2bf-32c27d6e6c67
REPORT RequestId: 98428165-89de-4e11-b2bf-32c27d6e6c67  Duration: 2019.29 ms    Billed Duration: 3245 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 99 MB  Init Duration: 1225.61 ms   

I tried using WORKDIR /app but then the packages installed using npm install is not found in the lambda.js file, so used ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

You can configure your lambda with ephermal storage (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-ephemeral-storage.html#:~:text=Lambda%20provides%20ephemeral%20storage%20for,using%20the%20Ephemeral%20storage%20setting.) May be change the path to /tmp and write to that location.

It seems 512MB Ephemeral storage is already there with the lambda function. However, even saving in /tmp/images/sample.png gives the same error.

Can you post the error message when you use /tmp location?
